# Lyx - "Use class defaults" does nothing

Tags: lyx

Using Lyx 2.2.1, after clicking "Save as Document Defaults" in the master document (menu Document / Settings / Document Class), I try to reproduce these settings in other files clicking on "Use Class Defaults" but nothing happens.

When I click on "Save as Document Defaults", I read `Document defaults saved in ~/.lyx/templates/defaults.lyx` in the Progress/Debug window, but when I click on "Use Class Defaults", nothing happens.

Am I using this Lyx feature correctly, is there something wrong?

Comment: I do not use those features, but my interpretation of is that "document default" is different from "class default". To me, "document default" means that when you start a new document, it will use your document defaults. "class defaults" to me means that LyX will use the defaults of the class (e.g. if you had previously specified two columns but normally the class defaults to single column, it will use that). As I said though, this is just my interpretation. If you think you found a bug, please report it at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the meaning of these buttons. Indeed, the User Guide states that the "Save as Document Defaults" outputs the current settings to `default.lyx` while "Use Class Defaults" restores the **class** parameters. Hence, I was looking for a "Use **Document** defaults"...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I exported the Lyx file as Tex code, converted it into my own `.cls` file, created the associated `.layout` file and assigned this new class as `Document class` for every document I wanted to apply the class defaults on.